# Material-UI: flip:false doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm new to Material-UI and jss and adding them to a right-to-left project.

I set it up [according to the docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#steps) and everything seems to work. MUI components are automatically flipped. However, we still need some components to not be flipped and work normally with ltr. I tried to work with the flip: false property [seen here in the docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#opting-out-of-rtl-transformation). It works for the simple example in the docs on normal divs (flips text-align: right to text-align: left). If I put the flip on a MUI component it doesn't do anything.

```
const style = {
    affected: {
        textAlign: 'right'
    },
    unaffected: {
        textAlign: 'right',
        flip: false
    }
}
```

Classes added to the component

```
<div>
    <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel 
            control={
                <Switch 
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.affected}
                />
            }
            label="Affected Switch"
            labelPlacement="start"
        />
    </FormGroup>
</div>

<div>
    <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel 
            control={
                <Switch 
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.unaffected}
                />
            }
            label="Unaffected Switch"
            labelPlacement="start"
        />
    </FormGroup>
</div>
```

In the example above I would expect this to render two switches where on the first one the styles on the x-axis are flipped to ltr. However, it only changes the text-align like in the docs example. I'm not sure if this is supposed to work and it's a bug or if there's even a way to achieve this. I haven't found any examples on the web on how to flip specific parts of a component and not just overriding the whole component to ltr and disabling the jss-rtl.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Added a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zm69om).

Comment: Can you create stackblitz to reproduce an issue?

Comment: [Here's a demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zm69om) I do think that I understand the issue now though, I think flip: false only works for the css rule set you wrote it on and it doesn't change anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14912) for Material-UI and got an answer back. [Here's a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cdoy9b) where I achieved the effect that I wanted.

```
const ltrTheme = {
  ...theme,
  direction: 'ltr'
}

function Demo({classes}) {
  return (
    <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch color="primary"/>
          }
          label="RTL Switch"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={ltrTheme}>
              <div dir="ltr">
                <Switch color="primary"/>
              </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          }
          label="LTR Switch"
        />
      </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

All you have to do is wrap the component you want LTR with a new theme with direction: ltr, and a div with dir='ltr'.